# Is there a Mac keyboard shortcut equivalent for Window's Ctrl+Alt+Tab?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, Ctrl+Alt+Tab leaves the Alt+Tab dialog open after releasing the shortcut, allowing for the entries to be navigated using the keyboard arrows and selected using Enter.

Is there an equivalent shortcut on Mac OS?

(I'm aware of Cmd+Tab. That's not equivalent because it requires holding Cmd to keep the dialog open)

Comment: What is it you're actually trying to achieve? I can see that holding the switcher open could be useful for some things, but since Spaces was added a decade or so ago I haven't ever felt the need to use Cmd/Tab at all. I put each app or 'work set' on its own Space & navigate directly to it using key commands. In effect, each app has its own call. eg Mail lives on Space 4 all by itself, so to get to Mail, frontmost, it's just Ctrl/4.

Comment: Does is matter? I'm trying to use BetterTouchTools to replace functionality that I used AHK for in Windows

Comment: It only matters to prevent an XY situation. If you don't want to share, then I've lost interest, sorry. I don't know of any way. See if someone else does. Wish you luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage this within System Preferences > Mission Control

I believe the default shortcut is CTRL + Up Arrow.

You can change the shortcut to be custom if you like, or you can assign Mission Control to a Hot Corner as well. This means if your mouse cursor moves to a specific corner of the screen it will also activate the selected command.

Sadly, there is no way to manually select each individual application window using a keyboard shortcut (like ALT + TAB in windows).

This question [has been asked before](https://superuser.com/questions/1717223/is-there-a-mac-keyboard-shortcut-equivalent-for-windows-ctrlalttab/1718099?noredirect=1#comment2652478_1718099) on the stack exchange forum and other community members have been suggesting some third party software you can try.

Comment: Thanks. That's the UI I'm looking for. Unfortunately, Mission Control doesn't allow selecting the window using the keyboard so not a 100% replacement.

Comment: Sorry Jacob, i've looked into this and unfortunately Mac do not offer this feature which to say the least is bizarre! I've modified my answer to suit.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob Scherber, check out [Mission Control Plus](https://www.fadel.io/missioncontrolplus) which I think achieves everything you mentioned.

Comment: Explaining HOW to use the tool you suggest to accomplish what they want will make this an answer. Currently it is only a comment, and this area is not for comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228987)